# Bootstrap Fading Carousel - 1px bump between transitions?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 with the carousel, but instead of it sliding to the left and right, it fades. The only thing is, when you're on a PC, there's this little 1px transition between each fade, as if the image is sliding to the left or right 1px.

My images are all the same size.

Can you tell me what the problem might be?

http://sayredesign.com/clients/tank-service/

Comment: Do u want the carousel to move right to left instead of fade?

Answer (score 0):

It fades because you use a custom.css which has all the CSS to make it fade. If you remove everything related to the carousel in the custom.css you should have the slide back.
For the transition, I got no clue, because I simply do not see that happening. Perhaps if you fixed the CSS, the problem will be solved too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.item` part after CAROUSEL in your custom.css

```
/* =============================
    CAROUSEL 
==============================*/

//other css

 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    width:100%;
    padding-left:1px
}

//other css

/* =============================
    FOOTER
==============================*/
```

Comment: But how do I make it fade instead of slide?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response! It seems like after a few hours of tinkering around with the code and really figuring out what I'm doing (hee!), it fixed itself. I must have had some bad code somewhere.